# How to render a textured object to a frambuffer texture, acquire by OpenCL, convert to OpenCV

Tags: opencv, opengl, opencl, render-to-texture

So I'm trying to combine the usefulness of all 3 libraries, I load an object with a texture:

```
// Load the model of the store, create a program with the shaders
GLint store = OpGL::initModel(MESH_PATH);
GLuint storeProgram = OpGL::initProgram(VS_GLSL_PATH, FS_GLSL_PATH);
glUseProgram (storeProgram);

// Find the location in the shader, for the texture image
GLuint TEX_ID = glGetUniformLocation(storeProgram, "tex_glsl");
GLuint TEX = OpGL::loadTexture(TEXTURE_IMAGE_PATH, 25);

// Bind texture in Texture Unit 0
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, TEX);

// Set
glUniform1i(TEX_ID, 0); // use texture 0
```

set up a framebuffer with a texture in GL:

```
GLuint g_fb = 0; // frame buffer
glGenFramebuffers (1, &g_fb);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, g_fb);

GLuint g_fb_tex = 0;
glGenTextures (1, &g_fb_tex);
glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_fb_tex);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexImage2D ( GL_TEXTURE_2D,0, GL_RGBA,640,480,      0,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,NULL   );
glFramebufferTexture2D (GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_fb_tex, 0);

GLuint g_db = 0; // depth buffer
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &g_db);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, g_db);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, 640, 480);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, g_db);

/* tell the framebuffer to expect a colour output attachment*/
GLenum draw_bufs[1] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 };
glDrawBuffers (1, draw_bufs);
```

create storage in CL:

```
cl_mem CL_image; //location for the gl rendering to reside in CL
CL_image = clCreateFromGLTexture2D(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, g_fb_tex, &err);
```

create a UMat:

```
cv::UMat Umat;
```

re-bind the original texture:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, TEX);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, g_fb);  // just as a precaution
```

render:

```
glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)        
glUseProgram (storeProgram);
glBindVertexArray (store);
glDrawArrays (GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 79227);
glfwPollEvents ();
glFlush();

    // pass the images to CL
err = clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects(queue, 1, &CL_image, 0, NULL, NULL);
cl_event wait;

cv::ocl::convertFromImage(CL_image, Umat);
cv::flip(Umat,Umat,0);
cv::imshow("CVforCLimage", Umat);
cv::waitKey(1);

err = clEnqueueReleaseGLObjects(queue, 1, &out_toCL_image, 0, 0, 0);
err = clFinish(queue);
```

Everything renders fine if I just send it to the screen (`glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);`)...  but I get a blue object instead of an orange object when I render it to CV.  Almost as though the original texture I loaded is not making it to the rendering.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: I tried it with:
     
     `cv::ocl::convertFromBuffer(out_toCL_image, Umat.step[0],Umat.rows,Umat.cols, Umat.type(), Umat);`

and I get:

`opencv-3.0.0/modules/core/src/ocl.cpp:5353: error: (-215) CL_MEM_OBJECT_BUFFER == mem_type in function convertFromBuffer`

Comment: So I tried a simpler rendering, without using glUseProgram and/or a textured object and it worked! so the problem I believe lies in the textures somehow... I must be muddling the textures.